# shouldStartLoadwithRequest not getting called in iPad Pro

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` object with the `delegate` set `webView.delegate = self` and  `UIView <UIWebViewDelegate>`

The following delegate call is getting called in all the iOS devices **except** the new **iPad Pro** with iOS 9.2.

```
   - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Does anybody knows why is not working with this specific device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The situation was that the server was using a Javascript library called **NativeBridge** in order to communicate with the **iOS app UIWebView** and this javascript library is not compatible with the iPad Pro.

Solution was to changed the NativeBridge library for another one more up to date on the server side.